# Keep Zoom Screen Share Active

Tags: ipad, sleep-wake, ipados, zoom.app

I am using Zoom on my iPad and sharing my screen.

Anytime the iPad screen blanks zoom stops sharing.  Then when I wake up the screen again I have to tell zoom to share.  Zoom does not stop, just the screensharing.

How can I keep my iPad screen shared even when the screen blanks?

How can I keep my iPad screen on so it does need to wake up?

Comment: Do you mean the display turns off or it just becomes blank (but display is not off, so hitting power does not turn it back on)?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to know this as well.

You didn't say what you tried, but to keep your iPad from going to sleep, go to Settings -> Display & Brightness -> Auto-Lock and change the time to "Never."

**[EDIT:]** Actually, this doesn't work. I've also tried "Refresh Background Apps," and that didn't work, either.